# Access overloaded functions in DLL

Tags: c++, winapi, direct2d

The [Direct2D](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371073%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) system library provides 4 overloaded versions for the `D2D1CreateFactory` function. Now suppose I'm loading the Direct2D library dynamically, and obtain the pointer to the CreateFactory function using the `GetProcAddress` system call. Which of the 4 overloaded functions will be returned? Is there a way to specify explicitly which function I need? Is this a downside of dynamic loading versus static linking, in that some of the overloaded functions will not be accessible?

```
HMODULE hDllD2D = ::LoadLibraryExA("d2d1.dll", 0, LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_SYSTEM32);
FARPROC fnCreateFactory = ::GetProcAddress(hDllD2D, "D2D1CreateFactory");
// What should be the call signature of `fnCreateFactory` ?
```

Comment: DLL functions are exported by name/ordinal only, not with any parameter info. As such, DLLs cannot export overloaded functions with same name. The compiler would have to decorate the exported names to make them unique.  When using `GetProcAddress()`, you would have to specify those specific decorated names, not the generic name being overloaded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function in the DLL is the most general one, [`D2D1CreateFactory(D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE,REFIID,D2D1_FACTORY_OPTIONS*,void**) function`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368034%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  If you peek inside the declarations in `d2d1.h`, you'll see that that function is declared, whereas the other overloads are just inline functions in the header which call through to the general function:

```
#ifndef D2D_USE_C_DEFINITIONS

inline
HRESULT
D2D1CreateFactory(
    __in D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE factoryType,
    __in REFIID riid,
    __out void **factory
    )
{
    return 
        D2D1CreateFactory(
            factoryType,
            riid,
            NULL,
            factory);
}


template<class Factory>
HRESULT
D2D1CreateFactory(
    __in D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE factoryType,
    __out Factory **factory
    )
{
    return
        D2D1CreateFactory(
            factoryType,
            __uuidof(Factory),
            reinterpret_cast<void **>(factory));
}

template<class Factory>
HRESULT
D2D1CreateFactory(
    __in D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE factoryType,
    __in CONST D2D1_FACTORY_OPTIONS &factoryOptions,
    __out Factory **ppFactory
    )
{
    return
        D2D1CreateFactory(
            factoryType,            
            __uuidof(Factory),
            &factoryOptions,
            reinterpret_cast<void **>(ppFactory));
}

#endif // #ifndef D2D_USE_C_DEFINITIONS
```

Comment: must be an html issue because that can't possibly be what the header file looks like.      *return
        D2D1CreateFactory(
            factoryType,
            __uuidof(Factory),
            reinterpret_cast<void **>(factory));* would not compile.  expects 4 arguments.  gets 3.

Comment: @thang: It compiles just fine.  The very first `inline` function above takes 3 arguments.

Comment: ah good call.  didn't see the thing at the top.  sorry about that.